# Почему при таймере переключения картинок появляется undefined

Tags: javascript

Всем здравствуйте! Подскажите пожалуйста, что не так в коде? Картинки переключаются, показывает последнюю и потом undefined. И, соответственно,  на этом таймер заканчивается

```
var myImage = document.getElementById("main-slider");
myImage.style.backgroundImage = 'url(assets/slide2.jpg)';
var imageArray = ["assets/slide1.jpg", "assets/slide3.jpg"];
var imageIndex = 0;
function changeImage() {
    if (imageIndex >= imageArray.lenght) {
        imageIndex = 0;
    }
    myImage.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + imageArray[imageIndex] + ')';

    mageIndex++;
 }
 var intervalHandle = setInterval(changeImage,5000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас опечатка: `imageArray.lenght` должно быть `imageArray.length`.

Соответственно `if (imageIndex >= imageArray.lenght)` всё время возвращает `false` и в какой-то момент `imageIndex` становится больше размера массива, а `imageArray[imageIndex]` возвращает `undefined`.

Comment: О Боже!))) Я 2ой день голову ломала, что не так. Больше всего ненавижу опечатки эти. Спасибо большое, что заметили.

Comment: Назрел, правда, еще вопрос один.. вот я устанавливаю:
myImage.style.backgroundImage = 'url(assets/slide2.jpg)'; 
myImage.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + imageArray[imageIndex] + ')';
 при этом картинки повторяются, как указать no-repeat ??? Какой должен быть синтаксис?

Comment: Если влоб, то `myImage.style.backgroundRepeat = 'no-repeat';`

Comment: Вот убрала повторение, теперь картинка обрезалась. Делать через `background-size : 100 % `? Или можно как-то по-другому??